# Flask & Tweepy - I can't handle the errors

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to print when there is a problem with Tweepy. When I look at Tweepy's docs, it seems possible with the `try except`. But after try except, user variable does not come. I get this error in user_profile_image: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment`.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

```
@app.route("/twitter", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def twitter():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        username = request.form.get('text')
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("myoauthhandlers")
        auth.set_access_token("myaccesstokens")
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        try:
            user = api.get_user(username)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
             print("Error")

        user_profile_image = user.profile_image_url.replace('normal', '400x400')
```

Comment: First of all you should define a default value for user before exception handling. But you need to find out why the exception is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `user` with a statement like `user = None` before the try/except block. Here, it gets defined in the scope of the try/except block, and so isn't accessible from outside of it, hence the exception.

Comment: It says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'profile_image_url'`

Comment: @zicxor Then you caught a ```tweepy.TweepError``` exception, and your ```user``` variable didn't get initialized in the block because of this. Instead of just printing the error, you should also quit the current function, or run different code than the ```profile_image_url``` line